# How to switching between InkCanvas and Canvas in UWP

Tags: xaml, canvas, uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I'm struggling with new UWP `InkCanvas` for my apps.If you are familiar with the new `InkCanvas` in UWP, I would truly appreciate your help.

I have a UWP apps need to switching between `InkCanvas` and `Canvas`, which I wish to use `InkCanvas` for Drawing, `Canvas` for creating Contents such as `RichEditbox`, `Image`, etc...

My XAML is below

```
<Grid Margin="100,0,100,0" Background="White" x:Name="MainGrid" PointerMoved="MyCanvas_PointerMoved" PointerReleased="MyCanvas_PointerReleased" PointerPressed="MyCanvas_PointerPressed">
            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" />
            <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" Canvas.ZIndex="0" />
            <!-- End "Step 2: Use InkCanvas to support basic inking" -->
</Grid>
```

I tried to make my `Canvas` `ZIndex` greater than `InkCanvas` by using

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Canvas.GetZIndex(MyCanvas) > 1)
        {
            Canvas.SetZIndex(MyCanvas, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas.SetZIndex(MyCanvas, 5);
        }
    }
```

However I can't make my `Canvas` come to the front, the `InkCanvas` keep Capturing my stroke if I Draw on it instead.

Does anyone know how to switch the Canvas and InkCanvas in my Grid without changing the `Visibility` of my `InkCanvas` to `Collapsed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `Canvas` background is empty (`null`), so it will not capture pointer input and will pass it through to the `InkCanvas`.

If you want to prevent this, you could set its `Background` to `Transparent`.

However, when you start putting some controls on the `Canvas` itself, they should capture the pen input and not let it through to the `InkCanvas`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. It works miracle with my requirements. I added some Textbox to the canvas dynamically it just works fine when I switching the InkCanvas to the front by setting a new ZIndex.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped :-) . Happy coding!